# && being used as an if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following a tutorial when I saw the following code snippet. I couldn't find anything about the and operator being used in this way. Is this a react thing? Can someone explain this or link to documentation that explains it?

---

```
{basket?.length > 0 && (
    <div className="checkout__right">
        <h2>Subtotal</h2>
        <Subtotal />
    </div>
)}
```

---

Comment: It's just a bit more of a concise way to express this idea- since this operator short-circuits, if the first part is not truthy the second part will not be evaluated.

Comment: This is known as "short-circuit evaluation" https://typeofnan.dev/short-circuit-evaluation-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This idiom uses the fact that logical operators, such as `&&` and `||` have short-circuit semantics. If the left hand operand of an `&&` operator is a `false`, the right hand operand isn't evaluated, because the result would be `false` anyway.

Thus, `&&` is used a conditional statement, evaluating the right hand operand only if the left hand operator is true.